# Dynamic Table is Flask and Jinga2 Nested for Loops

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am  trying to create a dynamic table in Flask with jinja2.  I have a employee table, skills table and a skills_a table ( this is a associative table with the employee id and skill id).

The expected output is

```
Employee   | Skill 1 | Skill 2 | Skill 3
Employee 1     X          X        X
Employee 2                X        X
Employee 3     X                   X
Employee 4                         X
```

What I am getting right now is

```
    Employee   | Skill 1 | Skill 2 | Skill 3
    Employee 1     X          X        X
    Employee 2     X          X    
    Employee 3     X     
    Employee 4     X
```

Any ideas on how to get this arranged correctly with a blank  where the employee does not have that skill would be great.

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Employee</th>
          {% for skill in skills %}
            <th>{{skill.description}}</th>
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for emp in employee %}
        <tr>
            <td><a href="/emp/edit/{{ assoc.id }}"> {{ emp.last_name }}, {{emp.first_name}} </a></td>
            {% for s in skills_a if emp.id == s.emp_id%}
                {% for skil in skills %}
                    {% if skil.id == s.skill_id %}
                        <td>{{ s.skill_id }}</td>
                        {% continue%}
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

Comment: Consider how you might arrange to emit a `<td></td>` pair to represent not having a skill.

Comment: I have tried to use else statements with a <td></td> in it what ends up happening is that I have too many blanks in the row.  For example if I have 2 Skills I end up with 2 blanks in the row between the first skill and the second skill because it is still running through the inner loop.